# An optimized TCP stack for accessing Wifi networks?

Tags: linux, networking, tcp

I am currently running TCP CUBIC on my linux machine. I would like to know if there is a more optimized version of TCP available for Linux for hosts accessing the network through weak WiFi links?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with a lossy network is that it takes a while before the sender retransmits the lost packet.  That's where any effort would have to be focused.  You can tune your TCP stack to retransmit packets sooner, basically trading bandwidth for latency.  You could go so far as to send every packet multiple times without waiting at all and be completely compatible with all existing TCP stacks.

A couple weeks ago there was an article about some companies working on just this, though aimed at high-speed cellular networks to provide more robust (and, as a result, higher throughput) communications when faced with significant (like 5%) packet loss.  It *reads* like it uses something like a "parity" packet that allows the receiver to reconstruct any one of several packets if one of the set gets lost, much like RAID5 can reconstruct any one disk in the event of a failure.  This, of course, would require support on both ends of the connection.

http://www.extremetech.com/computing/138424-increasing-wireless-network-speed-by-1000-by-replacing-packets-with-algebra

> With coded TCP, blocks of packets are clumped together and then
>   transformed into algebraic equations that describe the packets. If
>   part of the message is lost, the receiver can solve the equation to
>   derive the missing data. The process of solving the equations is
>   “simple and linear,” meaning it doesn’t require much processing on
>   behalf of the router/smartphone/laptop.